# JdbcDataSource x JdbcConnectionPool

Tags: jdbc, jetty, h2, hikaricp

I'm trying to understand the purpose and the diference between JdbcDataSource and JdbcConnectionPool.

Based in code either JdbcDataSource or JdbcConnectionPool implement javax.sql.DataSource.

My mains question is: When should I use one or other?

I have created an JNDI entry in jetty like:

```
<New id="h2ds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg><Ref refid="itracker" /></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/itracker_ds</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
      <Set name="url">db-url</Set>
      <Set name="password">user-password</Set>
      <Set name="user">user-password</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

Can I assume that org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource works like a pool or should I use some pool like DBCP or C3P0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never just assume a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation is a connection pool, especially not if it does not contain any properties related to connection pool configuration.

As far as I can tell from its documentation, [`org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html) is a simple `javax.sql.DataSource` (and `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource`) and **does not** provide connection pooling, while [`org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcConnectionPool.html) is a `javax.sql.DataSource` and provides very basic connection pool.

However in most cases you are probably better off using DBCP, HikariCP or C3p0, or the built-in connection pool if you are using a full application server (which Jetty is not).

Note that implementations of `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` are not a connection pool either, they are intended as a data source for supplying poolable connections **to** a `DataSource` providing connection pooling (eg from an application server).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my configuration to use HikariCP. Take a look:

```
<New id="h2ds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg><Ref refid="itracker" /></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/itracker_ds</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
      <Arg>
        <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
          <Set name="maximumPoolSize">20</Set>
          <Set name="dataSourceClassName">org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</Set>
          <Set name="password">db-password</Set>
          <Set name="username">db-user</Set>
          <Call name="addDataSourceProperty">
            <Arg>url</Arg>
            <Arg>db-url</Arg>
          </Call>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

Now I'm really using a connection pool.